# in ms access, how to group reports by record count

Tags: ms-access

i want to create a report to print invoices for certain start and end date.  However, I would like to print only a certain number of records per page. i.e. 15 records per page.  Next 15(16th-30th) will go on next page.  Also, need total amount for each page. How do I do it?  Reason is that I have preprinted statement form already with only 15 entries.  Cant seem to make it work with sorting and grouping.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If these records are of a fixed height, as is implied by a pre-printed form, you should check that "can shrink" and "can grow" properties are set to "no", if they are of a variable height, you can use a counter and set the visibility of a page-break, as described in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209006/en-us

As for totals, Allen Browne has this suggestion for page totals: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-11.html.

Comment: Read your suggestions and the websites and i think these helps.  I will try them.  Thanks in advance if it works hehe